# Splitting and runtime of log n

Tags: linked-list, runtime

Sorry, I made a mistake in my earlier question. Because of that I didn't get the answer I wanted.

The teacher told us that every time you divide something by 2, the run-time is likely to be log n. For instance, if we divide an array into two, each time we traverse one of the array, the run-time would be log n. However, we may run into a case with LinkedList where we may be easily misled. For instance, we may have an algorithm to set the nth element of the list to something else by starting from either the head or the tail in order to have a run-time of less than n. Logically, we may think that the run time would be log n, but it's not. Why is that? And how do you determine that?

Do we need to absolutely have splitting to get a run-time of log n? I don't think it makes any logical sense to say the run-time of n when the maximum run-time of the loop is n/2.

Answer (score 0):

I think some concepts need a bit of refining here, because the time complexity is only related to algorithm, not to the size of the data structure you're operating on.

> The teacher told us that every time you divide something by 2, the run-time is likely to be log n. For instance, if we divide an array into two, each time we traverse one of the array, the run-time would be log n.

Now, traversing an array, like

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
    variable = array[i];
}
```

runs in `O(n)`: the time needed to perform such an operation varies linearly with the size of the array. You will have `O(log n)` for operations like a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) on an array, but you cannot generalize this concept to all array operations, and especially not to those who need to iterate over the array.

Now, this sentence

> For instance, we may have an algorithm to set the nth element of the list to something else by starting from either the head or the tail in order to have a run-time of less than n.

leads me to believe that you think that the n as used in big O and what you call the "nth element" are directly related.  They aren't.  On a linked list your only option to go to element n is to go to the start of the list and follow the links down the element you're looking for (or in the case of a double linked list, go to the start or end depending on the position of the element you're looking for), so this operation has a time complexity of O(n), ie linearly related to the length of the collection.